# Sieve - Redirect incoming mail for all mailboxes within domain to one specific mailbox

Tags: centos, postfix, dovecot, spam-filter, sieve

Is it possible to set a global sieve filter to redirect mail to specific mailbox within receiving domain. I understand I can simply point out where I want mail to go in a filter like  bounce@example.com. But, I don't want mail from all domains end up in that one mailbox.

Example of what I want to achieve:
Email for contact@example.com with subject "Not delivered" be redirected to bounce@example.com. There are many domains on server, and each one has it's own bounce@ mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

For Postfix, which I assume is what you want you want from the tag (same option in Sendmail too) you would want to use the [`luser_relay` option](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#luser_relay) specifying a local account.

Comment: Not sure I understand.. From what I see luser_relay is a catchall mailbox that can be set up in postfix configuration? If I were to use a catchall for my purpose, how would I specify it in a sieve script?

What I need would work similar to this:
require ["copy", "fileinto"];
if header :contains "Subject" "tiger"
{
    redirect :copy "other@*.com";
    fileinto "Messages";
}

Where *.com is a domain that received an email originally.